# Yolov8 Classes names to txt

Tags: python, deep-learning, ros, yolov8

I'm using yolov8 and ROS to do object detection, so far so good. What I'm trying to implement at the moment is to take the name of the class that was identified and is in the processed image box and put it in a txt file with the day/time of detection and the name of the class, but it doesn't work.

Basically what I tried is already there in the code, I have no idea how to proceed further, I'm currently studying the Ultralytics documentation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from ultralytics import YOLO    
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import os
import datetime

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Crie um arquivo para armazenar os rótulos identificados
label_file = open("labels.txt", "w")

def start_node():
    rospy.init_node('detect_pump')
    rospy.loginfo('detect_pump node started')
    rospy.Subscriber("/image", Image, process_image)
    rospy.spin()

def process_image(msg):
    bridge = CvBridge()
    orig = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
    image = orig
    results = model(orig, verbose=True, imgsz=640)
    resultado= model.predict(source="0")
    cv2.imshow('IMAGEM RECEBIDA', orig)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    res_plotted = results[0].plot()
    cv2.imshow("result", res_plotted)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    # Obtenha a data e hora atual
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Concatene os rótulos identificados em uma única string
    labels_str = "\n".join(results.names)

    # Escreva os rótulos identificados como uma única string e a data/hora no arquivo
    label_file.write(f"Data/Hora: {current_time}\n")
    label_file.write(f"Labels: \n{labels_str}\n\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        start_node()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass

# Feche o arquivo após terminar de usar
label_file.close()`
```

What is coming out in the txt is not what I need, basically I just need the classes, but what appears is the following:

```
Data/Hora: 2023-10-14 17:08:30
Resultados: [ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Results object with attributes:

boxes: ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object
keypoints: None
keys: ['boxes']
masks: None
names: {0: 'person', 1: 'bicycle', 2: 'car', 3: 'motorcycle', 4: 'airplane', 5: 'bus', 6: 'train', 7: 'truck', 8: 'boat', 9: 'traffic light', 10: 'fire hydrant', 11: 'stop sign', 12: 'parking meter', 13: 'bench', 14: 'bird', 15: 'cat', 16: 'dog', 17: 'horse', 18: 'sheep', 19: 'cow', 20: 'elephant', 21: 'bear', 22: 'zebra', 23: 'giraffe', 24: 'backpack', 25: 'umbrella', 26: 'handbag', 27: 'tie', 28: 'suitcase', 29: 'frisbee', 30: 'skis', 31: 'snowboard', 32: 'sports ball', 33: 'kite', 34: 'baseball bat', 35: 'baseball glove', 36: 'skateboard', 37: 'surfboard', 38: 'tennis racket', 39: 'bottle', 40: 'wine glass', 41: 'cup', 42: 'fork', 43: 'knife', 44: 'spoon', 45: 'bowl', 46: 'banana', 47: 'apple', 48: 'sandwich', 49: 'orange', 50: 'broccoli', 51: 'carrot', 52: 'hot dog', 53: 'pizza', 54: 'donut', 55: 'cake', 56: 'chair', 57: 'couch', 58: 'potted plant', 59: 'bed', 60: 'dining table', 61: 'toilet', 62: 'tv', 63: 'laptop', 64: 'mouse', 65: 'remote', 66: 'keyboard', 67: 'cell phone', 68: 'microwave', 69: 'oven', 70: 'toaster', 71: 'sink', 72: 'refrigerator', 73: 'book', 74: 'clock', 75: 'vase', 76: 'scissors', 77: 'teddy bear', 78: 'hair drier', 79: 'toothbrush'}
orig_img: array([[[253, 238, 255],
        [253, 238, 255],
        [253, 238, 255],
        ...,
        [191, 213, 146],
        [191, 222, 129],
        [191, 222, 129]],

       [[253, 238, 255],
        [253, 238, 255],
        [253, 238, 255],
        ...,
        [191, 213, 146],
        [191, 222, 129],
        [191, 222, 129]],

       [[253, 241, 255],
        [253, 241, 255],
        [253, 241, 255],
        ...,
        [192, 209, 156],
        [192, 216, 142],
        [192, 216, 142]],

       ...,

       [[131, 118, 154],
        [131, 118, 154],
        [130, 117, 153],
        ...,
        [ 22,  26,  32],
        [ 20,  25,  28],
        [ 19,  24,  27]],

       [[131, 118, 156],
        [130, 117, 155],
        [129, 116, 154],
        ...,
        [ 24,  28,  34],
        [ 22,  27,  30],
        [ 21,  26,  29]],

       [[131, 118, 156],
        [130, 117, 155],
        [128, 115, 153],
        ...,
        [ 25,  29,  35],
        [ 23,  28,  31],
        [ 22,  27,  30]]], dtype=uint8)
orig_shape: (640, 480)
path: 'image0.jpg'
probs: None
save_dir: None
speed: {'preprocess': 3.4890174865722656, 'inference': 41.97049140930176, 'postprocess': 2.0608901977539062}]
```

Comment: so... you're asking how to write a string into a file? is that all? -- [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Comment: I see this is writing to the file, but there is no `flush()` or close. Is the data that is meant to be written just stuck in the buffer?

Comment: I posted the type of response I've been getting, I hope you can help me. This response is like a loop, which updates while the code runs, some data is modified, but the objects that are in the video do not appear, it always presents that number of classes that are not in the video

Answer (score 0):

for getting classes from result of YOLO,

use

```py
results = model('imagepath')
class_names = results[0].names
boxes = results[0].boxes
```

[Refer Docs](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/)